# Uncaught type error when looping through objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is like

```
var persons = [];
function Person(id, name) {
    this.id         = id;
    this.name       = name;
}
```

When I am trying to loop throught all persons, I'm getting an uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property "name" of undefined.

```
for (var person in persons) {
   console.log(persons[person]);
}
```

I noticed that my console is logging all persons and adding an property values after them

```
[Person, $family: function, $constructor: function, each: function, clone: function, clean: function…]
```

I'm pretty sure that that the code is breaking after looping the first person.

I'm using **jquery-1.11.1.js**

Any ideas how to get rid of this error? Thank you in advance.

Comment: How are you populating `persons` array?

Comment: I think you need to `console.log(person)` in your loop. `person` is an element of your array type `Person`, while `persons` array do not have key like that.